# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Visaul C++ SuiteSparse lib

Tags: visual-studio-2015, lnk2019, lnk2001, suitesparse, g2o

I used Visual C++ 2015.
I received the following errors when I tried to build my g2o sample code.

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_fflush 
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_fflush
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sqrt 
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol METIS_NodeComputeSeparator referenced in function cholmod_metis_bisector 
and so on.
```

About 172 errors are relative to LNK2001 and LNK2019. When I checked the file, it showed up most of the errors are relative to the Libs in SuiteSparse. I have already checked the library directories and additional library directories. But it still popped up these errors. I am new in the field of g2o. If someone can give me your kind hands, I'll very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I add some Libs below:
msvcmrtd.lib 
mscoree.lib
It works, but it popped out the exception during the running time.